# Cumulative Calculation - Based on Sample Data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

[image: 1]

Hi I am providing Sample Data below: Based on Sample data I want result output as per screenshot ..

```
create table mytable 
(
    emp_name varchar2(50)
    ,dept_number number
    ,Salary number
    ,Calendar_Year number
    ,Calendar_Period number
);

insert into mytable values ('Bob',6620,6500,2020,1);
insert into mytable values ('Bob',6620,1500,2020,1);
insert into mytable values ('Rachel',6620,3400,2020,1);
insert into mytable values ('Nancy',6620,1400,2020,1);
insert into mytable values ('Rachel',6620,4500,2020,2);
insert into mytable values ('Nancy',6620,2300,2020,2);
insert into mytable values ('Nancy',6620,1500,2020,3);
insert into mytable values ('Bob',6640,1200,2020,1);
insert into mytable values ('Bob',6640,1000,2020,1);
insert into mytable values ('Rachel',6640,1500,2020,1);
insert into mytable values ('Nancy',6640,1000,2020,1);
insert into mytable values ('Rachel',6640,4500,2020,2);
insert into mytable values ('Nancy',6640,1100,2020,2);
insert into mytable values ('Nancy',6640,1500,2020,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want to expand the rows and then take the most recent salary if it is not available:

```
select emp_name, dept_number, calendar_year, calendar_period,
       coalesce(sum(t.salary),
                lag(sum(t.salary) ignore nulls) over (partition by emp_name order by calendar_year, calendar_period)
                ) as salary
from (select distinct emp_name, dept_number from mytable) ed cross join
     (select distinct calendar_year, calendar_period from mytable) yp left join
     mytable t
     using (emp_name, dept_number, calendar_year, calendar_period)
group by emp_name, dept_number, calendar_year, calendar_period
order by calendar_year, calendar_period, dept_number, emp_name
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ce5e6ec0b177af8a41cc05adef625ce) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks.. Result of this query is not in expected output ( As per Screenshot). I provided sample data & expected Output screenshot. Only tough part for me is .. " If employee example Bob is get salary in period 1 and no salary in period 2 but I want display period 1 values as period 2 " This one I achieved.. But only challenge is ( for ex: Rachel  got salary 3400 in period 1 and 4500 in period 2 then I need to display 3400+4500 =7900 as period 2.

Answer (score 0):

seems like what Gordon provided is correct except you want to calculate lag() by emp_name and dept_number

```
select emp_name, dept_number, calendar_year, calendar_period,
       coalesce(sum(t.salary),
                lag(sum(t.salary) ignore nulls) over (partition by emp_name,dept_number order by calendar_year, calendar_period)
                ) as salary
from (select distinct emp_name, dept_number from mytable) ed cross join
     (select distinct calendar_year, calendar_period from mytable) yp left join
     mytable t
     using (emp_name, dept_number, calendar_year, calendar_period)
group by emp_name, dept_number, calendar_year, calendar_period
order by dept_number
         , Calendar_Period
         , emp_name
```

Comment: This requirement is not that much simple you  given query .. Did you check the screenshot that attached to this thread?

Comment: @AllenSolley what gordon provided is correct only there is minor error in calculating lag() , see my updated answer